# Kotlin - problems with "where" generic constraint

Tags: generics, kotlin

there is `ClassA` and `ClassB`, and also there is a function like shown below:

```
fun <T> doSomething(arg: T) where T: ClassA, T: ClassB {  }
```

It compiles perfect and works as expected when I call this function passing as the argument an object of a class ClassC:

```
class ClassC: ClassA(), ClassB
```

But when I have an object of type `Any` and do something like this:

```
if (arg is ClassA && arg is ClassB) {
    doSomething(arg)
}
```

The compiler doesn't compile this and says

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied
```

I expected the smart-cast should do the work but it didn't. Please tell me what's wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the reason for this is that Kotlin does not support intersection types, and thus, `arg` cannot be smart casted to `ClassA & ClassB`.

Comment: @AndreiTanana ClassA is a class, and ClassB is an interface

Comment: I like the idea of an anonymous type, defined as the combination of multiple types. By definition, a concrete subtype of it must exist if the ifs return true, and the API is simply the union of participating types' APIs (completely intuitive).

Answer (score 6):

Smart casts work, just not the way you expect them.
To help you understand, your check:

```
if (arg is ClassA && arg is ClassB) {
    doSomething(arg)
}
```

Is translated into:

```
if (arg is ClassA) {
    if (arg is ClassB) {
        doSomething(arg) // Only what's common between ClassA and ClassB is there
    }
}
```

Now, since there's nothing common between `ClassA` and `ClassB`, `Any` is inferred. Which is not what you expect.

You can force cast, of course:

```
if (arg is ClassA && arg is ClassB) {
    doSomething(arg as ClassC)
}
```

But that also may not work:

```
class ClassC: ClassA(), ClassB 

class ClassD: ClassA(), ClassB // This will cause ClassCast exception
```

In the end, using this type of constraint makes sense only in cases such as this:

```
open class ClassC: ClassA(), ClassB

class ClassD: ClassC()

class ClassE: ClassC()
```

Now, question arouse why `Any` is inferred. Shouldn't it be `Nothing`, since there's nothing in common?

Here we need to remember how Kotlin type system works.

If you write something like:

```
open class ClassA

open class ClassB
```

What you actually mean is the following:

```
open class ClassA : Any

open class ClassB : Any
```

And that's the common ancestor we infer.

`Nothing`, on the other hand, is a final class at the bottom of the class hierarchy. So not a single class could inherit from it.

Comment: "Any is inferred" - Why would Any be inferred? It's neither a ClassA nor a ClassB. We want a class that is both! Wouldn't `Nothing` be a more sensible inference?

Comment: That's a bit of a separate question, but I've updated my answer with the explanation about Kotlin type system.

Comment: Intuitively this makes sense if we start at Any, and think of the type checks as narrowing in on the type, i.e. what's our most specific type for C, given we know it's an A and it's a B? What's confusing is that this will never achieve what we actually want (unless A is a subtype of B or vice-versa), since the lowest common ancestor of 2 seperate types extends neither of them. The reason I asked about Nothing is because we really want a type that does extend both; Nothing extends everything (though not very usefully). For 0-1 classes + many interfaces we might find another common descendant.

Comment: `Nothing` doesn't extend anything in Kotlin.

Comment: Ah ok; `Nothing` is the Scala type for what I meant. Looks like Kotlin doesn't have an equivalent. Anyway, thank you for explaining smart casts.